# How to split cases for the cases for the repeated letters?

Tags: combinatorics

Given 4 letters are randomly selected from 10 letters in the word ENGAGEMENT. Find the probability that the 4 letters selected contains exactly 2 distinct letters.

Number of ways without restriction = 10 C 4 = 210 ; case 1: EEE,_ 1 way x 5C2= 10 ; case 2：NNGG, EEGG, EENN = 3ways.

Is this the correct way to analyse?

Comment: Welcome Tim. What have you tried so far ? Where are you having problem in splitting cases ?

Comment: split cases for$3+1$ and $2+2$

Comment: number of ways without restriction = 10 C 4 = 210 ; case 1: EEE,_ 1 way x 5C2= 10 ; case 2：NNGG, EEGG, EENN = 3ways

Comment: is this the correct way to analyse?

Answer (score 1):

We can regard the letters in the word ENGAGEMENT as the multiset
$$S = \{3 \cdot E, 2 \cdot N, 2 \cdot G, 1 \cdot A, 1 \cdot M, 1 \cdot T\}$$
where the number preceding a letter represents its multiplicity in the multiset.

To ensure that each outcome in the sample space is equally likely, we will treat each of the letters as being distinct.

Therefore, as you obtained, there are
$$\binom{10}{4}$$
elements in our sample space.

The favorable cases are those in which there are exactly two distinct letters in a multisubset.  This can occur in two ways.  Either the multisubset contains a letter with multiplicity $3$ and a letter with multiplicity $1$, or it contains two letters with multiplicity $2$.

*A multisubset with one letter with multiplicity $3$ and one letter with multiplicity $1$*:  The only letter that can have multiplicity $3$ is $E$.  We can select all three $E$s in one way.  We can select one of the two letters with multiplicity $2$ in two ways and one of the two copies of that letter in two ways, or select the only copy of one of the three letters with multiplicity $1$ to be the element with multiplicity $1$ in the multisubset.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{3}{3}\left[\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1} + \binom{3}{1}\binom{1}{1}\right]$$
such multisubsets.

*A multisubset with two letters with multiplicity $2$*:  There are only three letters with multiplicity at least $2$ in $S$.  $E$ has multiplicity $3$, while $G$ and $N$ each have multiplicity $2$.

A multisubset contains two $E$s and both copies of one of the other two letters:  We can select two of the three $E$s and both copies of one of the other two letters in $\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{2}$ ways.

The multisubset contains two $G$s and two $N$s:  There is one way to choose both $G$s and both $N$s.

Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$\dbinom{3}{3}\left[\dbinom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1} + \dbinom{3}{1}\binom{1}{1}\right] + \binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{2} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$

To obtain the desired probability, divide the number of favorable cases by the total number of elements in the sample space.